# How to add a pretrained model into a new model class

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to add in a pretrained resnet50 model, so I write this:

```
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.model = models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 53 * 53, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, args.num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        #x = self.model(x)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 53 * 53)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

I' not sure if my code is correct or i must add this line : `#x = self.model(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete unwanted layers from resnet50, as follows:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision import models
from torch.nn import functional as F
resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[:-2])
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 53 * 53, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        #x = self.model(x)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 53 * 53)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
  
model = ResNet(10)
model(torch.randn(100, 3, 224, 224)).shape
```

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-delete-layer-in-pretrained-model/17648/5